# VBA SQL:Accessing next record in the database

Tags: sql, vba

I have a db where the table has got the following fields

```
ID, Date,Field1,Field2,Field3, Field4
```

Here none of the fields are unique, but a combination of ID and Date will be unique.

For a given combination of ID and Date, I want to access the next record, in the table. The table is arranged with chronological dates for any given ID- but one thing is to be remembered that, only those dates are there which are weekdays(or holidays), so simple dateadd will not work.

I had been working with this code base

```
SELECT D1.Field4 FROM 
    (T1 
     INNER Join T1 As D1 
     ON D1.ID= T1.ID 
     AND D1.Date = DateAdd('d',10,T1.Date)
    )
  WHERE T1.Date = #1/7/2010# AND T1.ID =9;
```

Here its an inner join on a  simple dateadd and but this wont work the way I want when there are holidays in between

Please advise.

Soham

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the next one based on the inputs, rather than look for a specific one. Just look for matching ids with dates after the current one, and take the first in line.

eg:

```
select top 1
    t1.*,
    interval = datediff(dd, #1/7/2010#, t1.date)
from
    t1
where t1.id = 9 and t1.date > #1/7/2010#
order by t1.date
```

Comment: What if I want to access Day 1, Day 2 , Day 5 and Day 10 after the reference date. It becomes very cumbersome IMO to do it this way.

Comment: Your question said "I want to access the next record, in the table". If you want more rows, increase the number returns in the `select top 1` to `select top 10`

Comment: You could even generate a column in the data that said how many days in after the reference date it was.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider creating a new table with an ID and ValidDate column that tracks all of the valid dates that exist (excluding the weekends and holidays etc.).  Then I would join your data table on that table using the ID column in the ValidDates table to act as the range of the result set so that you can return any number of the next several days per your comment above.

If you would like to see some code, let me know and I could put some together.

UPDATE, I havent actually run this, but something like this should work for you.

```
SELECT D1.Field4 
FROM T1 INNER Join T1 As D1 
ON D1.ID= T1.ID 
WHERE T1.Date > #1/7/2010# AND T1.ID =9
AND D1.Date IN    
(SELECT ValidDate
FROM ValidDates
WHERE ValidDate BETWEEN T1.Date AND DateAdd('d',10,T1.Date));
```